# FileNotFoundException in onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-intent, base64, fileinputstream

I am trying to browse only two file-types: images or pdf.

Here is the source:

```
String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            myPermissions =new MyPermissions(TestDialog.this, 0, permissions);
            MyPermissions.EventHandler permHandler = new MyPermissions.EventHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handle() {

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("application/pdf");
                    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
            };

            myPermissions.doIfHasPermissions(permHandler);
```

Here is a my `onActivityResult` source:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String url = data.getData().getPath();
        File myFile = new File(url);
        Log.e("base64 ", getStringFile(myFile));


    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public String getStringFile(File f) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String encodedFile = "", lastVal;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];//specify the size to allow
        int bytesRead;
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Base64OutputStream output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);

        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output64.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        output64.close();
        encodedFile = output.toString();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    lastVal = encodedFile;
    return lastVal;
}
```

I would like to convert the selected file to Base64, but I get a `FileNotFoundException`. Does anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
```

Then try to log the value of uri.toString().

You will see that it starts with "content//....".

Do not try to find a file.

Instead of a FileInputStream use an InputStream.

```
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I try to browse only two type files,images or pdf

Your code has nothing much to do with files. It uses `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, which allows the user to choose a piece of content.

```
String url = data.getData().getPath();
```

This line is useless, unless the `Uri` has a scheme of `file`. Most likely, it has a scheme of `content`.

Stop using `File` and `FileInputStream`. Instead, get an `InputStream` from a `ContentResolver` (from `getContentResolver()`) and its `openInputStream()` method. You can pass in the `Uri`, and you will get an `InputStream` regardless of whether the `Uri` scheme is `file` or `content`.

Also note that your app is likely to crash with an `OutOfMemoryError`, except for fairly small files, as you will not have enough heap space to perform this conversion.